# How do I get specific integers from a column in a data set, and and separate each integer into a variable

Tags: python, predict, stock

In my code below, I am getting the polarity of certain news headlines. Then adding the polarity to a predicted stock price to make it more accurate. Currently, I am stuck on how to get a certain integer from a data set.

This is my code below:# Import the libraries

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import datetime
from datetime import date
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from textblob import TextBlob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

#Write a csv file with all the news
with open('AppleNewsSentiment6.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(['Date', 'Link', 'Headline', 'Description'])
  writer.writerow(['04/28/2021', 'https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/04/apple-introduces-airtag/', 'Apple is good', 'Apple is good'])
  writer.writerow(['04/29/2021', 'https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/04/imac-features-all-new-design-in-vibrant-colors-m1-chip-and-45k-retina-display/', 'iMac features all-new design in vibrant colors, M1 chip, and 4.5K Retina display', 'New Imac'])
  writer.writerow(['04/29/2021', 'https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/04/apple-commits-430-billion-in-us-investments-over-five-years/', 'Apple commits $430 billion in US investments over five years', 'Apple invested 430 billion into the USA'])
  writer.writerow(['04/29/2021', 'https://www.nbcnews.com/shopping/tech-gadgets/apple-new-2021-products-n1265706', 'Apple unveils new 2021 products: iPad Pro, AirTag and more', 'Apple has new products'])
  writer.writerow(['04/30/2021', 'https://www.npr.org/2021/04/26/990943261/apple-rolls-out-major-new-privacy-protections-for-iphones-and-ipads', 'Apple is horrible', 'Apple is not improving privacy'])
  writer.writerow(['04/30/2021', 'https://www.npr.org/2021/04/26/990943261/apple-rolls-out-major-new-privacy-protections-for-iphones-and-ipads', 'Apple is Bad', 'Apple is bad'])

#Load the data
from google.colab import files
files.upload()

#Store the data
dataF = pd.read_csv('AppleNewsSentiment6.csv')
#Set the date as the index
dataF = dataF.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(dataF['Date'].values))
#Show the data
dataF

#Create a function to get the polarity
def getPolarity(text):
  return TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity

#Add 1 column to the dataset
dataF['Polarity'] = dataF['Headline'].apply(getPolarity)

#Show the data set with the new column
dataF

#Create a function to compute negitive, neutral, and positive sentiments
def getSentiment(score):
  if score < 0:
    return 'Negitive' 
  elif score == 0:
    return 'Neutral'
  else:
    return 'Positive'

#Create a new column with these values
dataF['Sentiment'] = dataF['Polarity'].apply(getSentiment)

#Show the data
dataF

#Plot and visualise the sentiment count
plt.title('Sentiment Analysis')
dataF['Sentiment'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.xlabel('Sentiments')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.show()

#Plot the sum of the polarity for each date
plt.figure(figsize=(12.33, 4.5))
plt.title('Sentiment sum/time')
polarity = dataF.groupby(['Date']).sum()['Polarity']
plt.plot(polarity.index, polarity)

#Show the sum of the polarity for each date
polarity

#Get the count of the articles
polarity_count = dataF.groupby(['Date']).count()['Polarity']
#Show the data
polarity_count

#Show the average sentiment for each day
polarity_avg = polarity / polarity_count
polarity_avg

#Plot the average sentiment over time
plt.figure(figsize=(13, 4.5))
plt.plot(polarity_avg.index, polarity_avg)
```

I have a lot more code to predict the price of any stock, but all I need to know is how to get values out of a data set.

This is the data set below:

```
Date
04/28/2021    **0.700000**
04/29/2021    **0.161616**
04/30/2021   **-0.850000**
Name: Polarity, dtype: float64
```

I want to get each of the integers surrounded by the 'stars', and set a variable equal to each one of them. Is there any way to do this?
Thank you.

Update: I have tried regular expressions; they do not work.

Comment: is the data set you show the content of the `dataF` variable? If you are trying to extract numbers for a string then have a look at regular expressions.

Comment: No, it is a part of the polarity_average variable, but I will still take a look at regular expressions. Thank you for the suggestion!